# Python - Extract and reformat field names from rows of data

Tags: python, regex, text, dictionary, header

I have a flat text file (infile) that I would like to restructure. It has a few tab-delimited columns and looks something like this:

```
 Person1    HEIGHT=60;WEIGHT=100;AGE=22
 Person2    HEIGHT=62;WEIGHT=101;AGE=25
 Person3    HEIGHT=64;WEIGHT=110;AGE=29
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
 PERSON    HEIGHT    WEIGHT    AGE
 1         60        100       22
 2         62        101       25
 3         64        110       29
```

You can see that the second column actually contains several semicolon-delimited  header/value fields, and I want to restructure them into typical column header rows.

Right now I have:

```
for line in infile:
        line = line.split("\t")
        line_meta = line[1].split(";")
        print line_meta
```

I am thinking the best solution will to now loop over the line_meta variable, use use regular expressions to detect header names (detect strings which start with multiple capital letters and ends with "="_), add each header to a dictionary as a key, and then store the rest of the string as the value.  Then, for the next row, if the same header is detected just append to the existing dictionary.

Can anyone help with this code or provice feedback about how to proceed?

Thank you

**EDIT:**  Thank you for your responses.  I simplified my data for this example, but here is what one of the actual meta columns looks like (still ; delimited, but values types are mixed):

```
       P=0.9626;IPU=.$.+1T.+1T.+;IRF=ncRNA;IUC=UTR3;IGN=NCRNA00115;IGI=NCRNA00115,RP11-206L10.16-001;IET=0;IEO=0;IEN=.;IHT=0;IHVC=0;IHD=.;IHI=.;IHN=.;IDI=.;IDN=.;ITMAF=.;ITAMR=.;ITASN=.;ITAFR=.;ITEUR=.;ITNRB=+A;ISF=.;ISD=.;ISM=.;ISX=.;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use one regular expression to split out the key=value pairs:

```
import re

key_value = re.compile('(?P<key>[A-Z]+)=(?P<value>\[^\s=;]+)(?:(?=;)|$)')
```

This expression uses named groups, but you could do without those if you find it easier to read:

```
key_value = re.compile('([A-Z]+)=([^\s=;])(?:(?=;)|$)')
```

The `(?:..)` group is a non-capturing group; it is only used here to demark what the `|` or symbol applies to. The pattern matches uppercase characters before the `=` symbol, and anything that is *not* whitespace, a `=` or `;` character, provided that there is a `;` *or* the end of the string right after the value.

This splits out keys and values for each line:

```
>>> key_value = re.compile('(?P<key>[A-Z]+)=(?P<value>[^\s=;]+)(?:(?=;)|$)')
>>> key_value.findall('Person1\tHEIGHT=60;WEIGHT=100;AGE=22')
[('HEIGHT', '60'), ('WEIGHT', '100'), ('AGE', '22')]
```

This can easily then be turned into a dictionary:

```
>>> dict(key_value.findall('Person1\tHEIGHT=60;WEIGHT=100;AGE=22'))
{'AGE': '22', 'WEIGHT': '100', 'HEIGHT': '60'}
```

You can then write these with, for example, using [`csv.DictWriter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv
import re

key_value = re.compile('(?P<key>[A-Z]+)=(?P<value>[^\s=;]+)(?:(?=;)|$)')

with open(inputfilename) as infile, open(outputfilename, 'wb') as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, ('PERSON', 'HEIGHT', 'WEIGHT', 'AGE'), delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()

    for line in infile:
        person = line.split('\t', 1)[0]
        row = dict(key_value.findall(line))
        row['PERSON'] = person
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Demo based on your real data sample:

```
>>> dict(key_value.findall('       P=0.9626;IPU=.$.+1T.+1T.+;IRF=ncRNA;IUC=UTR3;IGN=NCRNA00115;IGI=NCRNA00115,RP11-206L10.16-001;IET=0;IEO=0;IEN=.;IHT=0;IHVC=0;IHD=.;IHI=.;IHN=.;IDI=.;IDN=.;ITMAF=.;ITAMR=.;ITASN=.;ITAFR=.;ITEUR=.;ITNRB=+A;ISF=.;ISD=.;ISM=.;ISX=.;\n'))
{'ISX': '.', 'ITAMR': '.', 'IDN': '.', 'ISM': '.', 'IDI': '.', 'ISF': '.', 'ISD': '.', 'ITMAF': '.', 'IUC': 'UTR3', 'IGI': 'NCRNA00115,RP11-206L10.16-001', 'ITNRB': '+A', 'IHVC': '0', 'IET': '0', 'ITASN': '.', 'ITEUR': '.', 'ITAFR': '.', 'IEO': '0', 'IEN': '.', 'IGN': 'NCRNA00115', 'IRF': 'ncRNA', 'P': '0.9626', 'IHT': '0', 'IHI': '.', 'IHN': '.', 'IPU': '.$.+1T.+1T.+', 'IHD': '.'}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Could you suggest how to edit the key_value to accomodate values that are not just numeric?  Your regex is very complicated for my level of understanding but I tried modifying it to `'(?P<key>[A-Z]+)=(?P<value>\S+)(?:(?=;)|$)'` and it did not ascertain the fields properly

Comment: @alexhli: You could use `\w+` for word characters, so a-z plus 0-9.

Comment: @alexhli: Ah, I missed the actual example you provided. I've updated the regular expression to be more permissive and posted a demo for you.

Comment: Your new demo works great!  last question (I hope), for some reason it is now printing "" around the last field, any idea why?  so it looks like `Person1 60 100 "22
"`

Comment: It is including spaces; we can add whitespace as disallowed in the character class: `[^\s;=]+`. The CSV file uses quotes around the value to show that the extra space after `22` is part of the value still.

Comment: thanks so much for your responsiveness, I'd give you more upvotes if I could

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
data = open('testfile.dat').read().split('\n')

def newcmp(x,y): 
    rv = cmp(len(x[1]), len(y[1]))
    if rv: return rv
    else: return cmp(x[0], y[0]) # alphabetical 

persons = {}
attributes = {}
nAttrs = 0
for l in data:
    pname , pvals = line.split('\t')[:2]
    for atName, atVal in (x.split('=') for x in pvals.psplit(';'))
        try:
            persons[pName][attributes[atName]] = atVal
        except KeyError:
            attributes[aName] = nAttrs
            persons[pName][attributes[atName]] = atVal
            nAttr += 1

headers = ['NAME'] + range(nAttrs)
for x in attributes.keys(): headers[attributes[x]+1] = x
values = []
for pName, pVals in sorted(persons.items(), cmp=newcmp)
    if len(pVals) < nAttrs: pVals += [0 for x in xrange(nAttrs - len(pVals))]
    values.append('\t'.join(('%d'%x for x in pVals)))

outfh = open('outputfile.dat', 'w')
outfh.write('%s\n%s\n'%('\t'.join(headers), '\n'.join(values)))
outfh.close()
```